# Creating directories & subdirectories based on user input than display created directories?

Tags: scripting

I wrote this script:

*Yes I know this code does not work, but maybe I can get my point across.*

```
echo -n "Please enter your base directory name: "
read BASE
mkdir -p "$BASE"
mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE1"
mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE2"
mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE3"
mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE4"
mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE5"
ls -d */
```

Okay so doing a bit of online research I think I might need to use globs for this, but my professor really didn't mention them. The requirements for this script are that it ask for a base directory name, and than creates a base directory plus exactly 5 subdirectories based on the user input than outputs the created directories in an echo or ls command.

Comment: `"${BASE}1"` etc. and you don't need caps.

Comment: The curlies are needed to tell the shell that 1 (2,3,...) is not part of the indentifier.

Comment: Ah thank you I totally forgot about that thank you! Now to tinker with this some more.

Comment: If you're on bash, ksh, or zsh, you can make the directory creation part a one liner: `mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE"{1..5}`

Comment: `echo "$BASE"; ls -A "$BASE"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate $BASE from the numbers (1..5), otherwise sh will interpret what you want as a variable named e.g . `$BASE1` rather than giving you the value of `$BASE` with a `1` appended.

Here's a fixed and slighly improved version of your script.

```
echo -n "Please enter your base directory name: "
read BASE
mkdir -p "$BASE" "$BASE/$BASE"{1..5}
ls -1d $BASE $BASE/*
```

If you're not using bash or zsh or ksh or any other shell that supports `{1..5}` then you can do this instead:

```
echo -n "Please enter your base directory name: "
read BASE
mkdir -p "$BASE" 
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do mkdir -p "$BASE/$BASE$i" ; done
ls -1d $BASE $BASE/*
```

Comment: Cas you make it look too easy! I really appreciate your response. I'm going to review your code and try and learn a thing or two. Your first response before you edited it worked. I see you also posted 2 other ways to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, I'd do:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
base="$1" #Get it from the argument, prompts for input aren't very unixy
mkdir -p "$base/$base"{1..5}
ls -d */
```

In `dash` you can't use `{1..5}`, so:

```
for i in `seq 5`; do mkdir -p "$base/$base${i}"; done
```

Comment: I'm using bash so the first one works :) thanks for showing both though!

Comment: @PSkocik - it's not very unixy but it's what the assignment asked for....it's wise to give professors what they want, otherwise they get cranky.